# Custom Toast inflater must be initialized

Tags: kotlin, android-toast

i have this fun

```
private fun testToast(){
        val inflater:LayoutInflater
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_message)
        val toast = Toast(this.context)
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP,0,70)
        toast.duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        toast.view =view
        toast.show()
    }
```

the main idea its to change the background color of the toast without getting a square toast

in this code i get an error in inflater.inflate

(inflater must be initialized)

this is the test xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_toast_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@color/background_blue"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_toasticon"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:textColor="@color/gauge_red"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="Prueba prueba PRUEBA"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

con someone help me or annother way to do a toast with custom color.

change the color of a toast with rounded corners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared the `inflater` variable but never assigned anything to it (using `=`). You can’t use a variable’s value if you haven’t assigned anything to it yet.

If this function is in an Activity, you can delete the line that declares `val inflater` and replace `inflater.` with `layoutInflater.` to use the property of the Activity. If it’s in a Fragment, use `requireActivity().layoutInflator.`.

By the way, the latest version of Android has deprecated setting a custom view for your toast. On Android R and later if you set a view on your Toast, it won’t show. They want you to use SnackBars instead. There might be a third party library available that could help create something more similar to Toasts.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a drawable resource to achieve it

toast_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/teal_200" />
    <corners android:radius="48dp" />
</shape>
```

and use this drawable for background of toast view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_toast_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@drawable/toast_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:text="Prueba prueba PRUEBA"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqLVd.png)

Comment: yeah but when i write the code in the function inflater give error